# Visibility Of AdminPresentationCollection Annotations - Broadleaf-Commerce

Tags: broadleaf-commerce

I using broadleaf-commerce famework for my program. I just want to know, how to visibility of AdminPresentationCollection in to config entity file. I config in js file but it doesn't work. 
This's my entity. It use @AdminPresentation annotations and @AdminPresentationCollection annotations :

```
@Entity
@Table(name="BLC_PRICE_LIST")
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED)
@Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.READ_WRITE, region="blStandardElements")
@SQLDelete(sql="UPDATE BLC_PRICE_LIST SET ARCHIVED = 'Y' WHERE PRICE_LIST_ID = ?")
@DirectCopyTransform({
        @DirectCopyTransformMember(templateTokens = DirectCopyTransformTypes.SANDBOX, skipOverlaps=true),
        @DirectCopyTransformMember(templateTokens = DirectCopyTransformTypes.MULTITENANT_CATALOG)
})
public class PriceListImpl implements PriceList, PriceListAdminPresentation, AdminMainEntity {

        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

        @Id
        @GeneratedValue(generator = "PriceListId")
        @GenericGenerator(
            name="PriceListId",
            strategy="org.broadleafcommerce.common.persistence.IdOverrideTableGenerator",
            parameters = {
                @Parameter(name="segment_value", value="PriceListImpl"),
                @Parameter(name="entity_name", value="com.community.core.pricelist.domain.PriceListImpl")
            }
        )

        @Column(name = "CUSTOMER_RESTRICTION_RULE_TYPE")        
        @AdminPresentation(
                friendlyName = "prices_rule_customer_title_group",
                group = GroupName.Customer, order = FieldOrder.TargetCustomer,
                fieldType=SupportedFieldType.BROADLEAF_ENUMERATION,
                broadleafEnumeration="com.community.core.pricelist.service.type.PriceListCustomerRestrictionRuleType",
                defaultValue = "prices_rule_customer_available_for_all_customer",
                tooltip = "prices_rule_customer_tooltip"
        )
        protected String customerRestrictionRuleType;


        @OneToMany(mappedBy = "priceList", 
                targetEntity = PriceListPriceListRuleXrefImpl.class, 
                cascade = { CascadeType.ALL },
                orphanRemoval = true)
        @MapKey(name = "key")
        @Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.READ_WRITE, region="blPriceLists")
        @AdminPresentationMapFields(
            toOneTargetProperty = "priceListRule",
            toOneParentProperty = "priceList",
            mapDisplayFields = {
                @AdminPresentationMapField(
                    fieldName = RuleIdentifier.CUSTOMER_FIELD_KEY,
                    fieldPresentation = @AdminPresentation(
                            fieldType = SupportedFieldType.RULE_SIMPLE,
                            group = GroupName.Customer,
                            order = FieldOrder.CustomerRule,
                            ruleIdentifier = RuleIdentifier.CUSTOMER,
                            friendlyName = "RESTRICT TO THE FOLLOWING CUSTOMERS"
                    )
                )
                ,
                @AdminPresentationMapField(
                    fieldName = RuleIdentifier.PRICING_CONTEXT_FIELD_KEY,
                    fieldPresentation = @AdminPresentation(
                            fieldType = SupportedFieldType.RULE_SIMPLE,
                            group = GroupName.PricingContext,
                            order = FieldOrder.PricingContext,
                            ruleIdentifier = RuleIdentifier.PRICING_CONTEXT,
                            friendlyName = "price_list_rule_pricing_context_lab")
                )
                ,
                @AdminPresentationMapField(
                    fieldName = RuleIdentifier.REQUEST_FIELD_KEY,
                    fieldPresentation = @AdminPresentation(
                            fieldType = SupportedFieldType.RULE_SIMPLE,
                            group = GroupName.PricingContext,
                            order = 9000,
                            ruleIdentifier = RuleIdentifier.REQUEST,
                            friendlyName = "LIMIT TO CERTAIN WEB REQUESTS?")
                )
            }
        )
        Map<String, PriceListPriceListRuleXref> priceListMatchRules = new HashMap<String, PriceListPriceListRuleXref>();


        @OneToMany(mappedBy = "priceList", targetEntity = PriceModifierImpl.class,
                    cascade = { CascadeType.ALL }, orphanRemoval = true)
        @Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.READ_WRITE, region = "blPriceLists")
        @BatchSize(size = 50)
        @AdminPresentationCollection(  friendlyName = "Price Modifiers",        
                                       group = GroupName.PricingContext,
                                       order = 20000,
                                       addType = AddMethodType.PERSIST
                                       ,showIfFieldEquals={
                                            @org.broadleafcommerce.common.presentation.FieldValueConfiguration(
                                                    fieldName = "customerRestrictionRuleType",
                                                    fieldValues = {"ALL_CUSTOMERS", "A","B", "a" , "b"}
                                            )
                                        }
        )
        protected List<PriceModifier> priceModifier = new ArrayList<PriceModifier>(100);

        @Column(name = "ERROR_CODE")
        @AdminPresentation(friendlyName = "productOption_errorCode",
            group = GroupName.PricingContext, order = 21000)
        protected String errorCode;

    @Override
    public Boolean getIsPricingContext() {
        return isPricingContext;
    }

    @Override
    public void setIsPricingContext(Boolean isPricingContext) {
        this.isPricingContext = isPricingContext;
    }

    @Override
    public Boolean getIsRequest() {
        return isRequest;
    }

    @Override
    public void setIsRequest(Boolean isRequest) {
        this.isRequest = isRequest;
    }



    @Embedded
    protected ArchiveStatus archiveStatus = new ArchiveStatus();




        @Override
        public Long getId() {
                return id;
        }

        @Override
        public void setId(Long id) {
                this.id = id;
        }

        public String getCustomerRestrictionRuleType() {
            return customerRestrictionRuleType;
            //return DynamicTranslationProvider.getValue(this, "customerRestrictionRuleType", customerRestrictionRuleType);
        }


        public void setCustomerRestrictionRuleType(String customerRestrictionRuleType) {
            this.customerRestrictionRuleType = customerRestrictionRuleType;
        }


        @Override
        public Map<String, PriceListPriceListRuleXref> getPriceListMatchRulesXref() {
           return priceListMatchRules;
        }

        @Override
        public void setPriceListMatchRulesXref(Map<String, PriceListPriceListRuleXref> priceListMatchRulesXref) {
           this.priceListMatchRules = priceListMatchRulesXref;
       }


        @Override
        public List<PriceModifier> getPriceModifier() {
            return priceModifier;
        }

        @Override
        public void setPriceModifier(List<PriceModifier> priceModifier) {
            this.priceModifier = priceModifier;
        }

        @Override
        public Character getArchived() {
           ArchiveStatus temp;
           if (archiveStatus == null) {
               temp = new ArchiveStatus();
           } else {
               temp = archiveStatus;
           }
           return temp.getArchived();
        }

        @Override
        public void setArchived(Character archived) {
            if (archiveStatus == null) {
                archiveStatus = new ArchiveStatus();
            }
            archiveStatus.setArchived(archived);
        }

        @Override
        public boolean isActive() {
            return DateUtil.isActive(startDate, endDate, true) && 'Y'!=getArchived();
        }

        @Override
        public <G extends PriceList> CreateResponse<G> createOrRetrieveCopyInstance(MultiTenantCopyContext context) throws CloneNotSupportedException {
            CreateResponse<G> createResponse = context.createOrRetrieveCopyInstance(this);
            if (createResponse.isAlreadyPopulated()) {
                return createResponse;
            }
            PriceList cloned = createResponse.getClone();
            cloned.setName(name);

            return  createResponse;
        }

    @Override
    public String getMainEntityName() {
        return getName();
    }
    @Override
    public PriceList createPriceList(){
        return new PriceListImpl();
    }
}
```

And this is my enum:

```
public static final PriceListCustomerRestrictionRuleType ALL_A = new PriceListCustomerRestrictionRuleType("ALL_CUSTOMERS", "AVAILABLE TO ALL CUSTOMERS");
    public static final PriceListCustomerRestrictionRuleType A_RULE_ASSIGNMENT_A = new PriceListCustomerRestrictionRuleType("CUSTOMER_RULE_ASSIGNMENT_CUSTOMERS", "CUSTOMER RULE AND ASSIGNMENT TO CUSTOMERS");
```

And this is my js file:

```
(function($, BLCAdmin) {

    $.each(['com.community.core.pricelist.domain.PriceList'], function(idx, clazz) {

        BLCAdmin.addDependentFieldHandler(
            clazz,            
            '#field-customerRestrictionRuleType',
            '#field-priceListMatchRules---CUSTOMER',
            'CUSTOMER_RULE_ASSIGNMENT_CUSTOMERS'
        );

        BLCAdmin.addDependentFieldHandler(
            clazz,
            '#field-isPricingContext',
            '#field-priceListMatchRules---PRICING-CONTEXT',
            'true'
        );

        BLCAdmin.addDependentFieldHandler(
            clazz,
            '#field-isRequest',
            '#field-priceListMatchRules---REQUEST',
            'true'
        );

       BLCAdmin.addDependentFieldHandler(
            clazz,
            '#field-customerRestrictionRuleType',
            '#field-priceModifier',
            'ALL_CUSTOMERS'
       );

        /*BLCAdmin.addDependentFieldHandler(
            clazz,
            '#field-customerRestrictionRuleType',
            '#field-priceModifier',
            'ALL_CUSTOMERS'
        );*/
    });


    /*$.each(['com.community.core.pricelist.domain.PriceModifier'], function(idx, clazz) {
        BLCAdmin.addDependentFieldHandler(
            clazz,
            '#field-isTargetedItemsRule',
            '#field-priceModifierMatchRules---PRODUCT',
            'true'
        );
    });*/

})(jQuery, BLCAdmin);
```

Help me! Many thank!